# Limit JTable to 100 Rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, limit, rows

Is there a function in Java library that would limit JTable size only to a number of rows that you set? I cant seem to find anything that would help me with it.

My program allows you to add and remove items from the JTable. [JTable counts the number of rows in use and returns the number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867838/jtable-counts-the-number-of-rows-in-use-and-returns-the-number)
Is there a way to limit number of rows only to 100.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTable counts the number of rows in use and returns the number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867838/jtable-counts-the-number-of-rows-in-use-and-returns-the-number)

Comment: The duplicate was a different question that i asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ou can use `setRowCount(int rowCount)` on you table dataModel.

which will sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model If the new size is less than the current size, all rows at index rowCount and greater are discarded.

For Example:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabel1.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(100); // though I would use some variable here
tabel1.setModel(dtm);
```

Please find the explanation [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount%28int%29)

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but what I was looking for is bit  something different. What i have is a good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867838/jtable-counts-the-number-of-rows-in-use-and-returns-the-number  that adds and removes cars, I'm looking to set a limit to amount of cars can be added. Sorry for the lack of info at the start

Comment: @Eddie Please accept the answer if you are satisfy. Which will keep us motivated to help other.

Comment: Changed the code around just a wee bit and implemented an array with a max of 100 items :) seem to kind of done the job.

Comment: @Eddie thats a good news and I am glad that your problem has been resolved. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to set a limit to amount of cars can be added.

Then override the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel to not allow you to add more than 100 rows of data.

There is nothing in the API that limits the number of rows since the API is meant to be dynamic.